# How can I identify what process is sending emails?

Tags: ubuntu, email, background-process, smtp, ssmtp

My email service provider has informed me that I keep hitting my daily SMTP quota limit and has identified one of my servers as sending email from a root account.

I've disabled any cronjobs that were sending emails and then checked my mail logs and syslog and can see the mail process they're referring to is still running each minute.

However, it's not running from the cron, and appears to be a standalone SMTP process.

```
tail -f ./var/log/syslog
Jul 15 09:25:02 serveralias sSMTP[1359056]: Creating SSL connection to host
Jul 15 09:25:03 serveralias sSMTP[1359056]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Jul 15 09:25:06 serveralias sSMTP[1359056]: Sent mail for root@serveralias.com (221 2.0.0 Bye) uid=1000 username=not-root-account outbytes=1332
Jul 15 09:26:01 serveralias sSMTP[1359129]: Creating SSL connection to host
Jul 15 09:26:03 serveralias sSMTP[1359129]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Jul 15 09:26:05 serveralias sSMTP[1359129]: Sent mail for root@serveralias.com (221 2.0.0 Bye) uid=1000 username=not-root-account outbytes=1332
```

Is there a way I can identify this process and see what it's doing?  OS is Ubuntu Server 20.04

Comment: Did you try to get user and process with: lsof -i:25

Comment: Just managed to capture the process I think   - root@serveralias:/# lsof -i:25
COMMAND      PID     USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sendmail 1362800 not-root-user    3u  IPv4 17532561      0t0  TCP host.serveralias.com:56306->sub5.mail.dreamhost.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED) .   Tired it again a minute later to capture the next one, the ID obviously changes but the DEVICE remains unchanged.  Can I use the "device" to track down the culprit?

Comment: I would use: "ps aux | grep PID" to get the exact process

Answer (score 1):

In this case, i would do a quick and dirty wrapper around sendmail command which is usually used to send email from process, crontab, etc.:

1. Rename original sendmail to sendmail.real: `mv /usr/bin/sendmail{,.real}`
2. Write the following script as `/usr/bin/sendmail`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   calling_process=$(ps ax -o pid,cmd|grep -P "^[ ]*${PPID}"|awk '{print $2}')
   echo "${date}: Called by ${PPID} (resolves as ${calling_process})"
   /usr/bin/sendmail.real $*
   ```
3. Put the right permissions on the script (`chmod 755` /usr/bin/sendmail`).

This must be enought :)